# xcode ios 7 fixed height of tableview with statusbar change and in ib

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios7, height, autosize

I need to make my tableview not change height at all. Not shrink when statusbar is changed. I am using storyboard and i have another viewcontroller with a embeded tableview where the tableviews height stays the same no matter what.

In interface builder when switching from 3.5" to 4" the tableview changes size. I have fixed this by setting height programmatically. However the height changes when statusbar is changed. I cant seem to find the property in IB that turns off this autosizing feature for my second tableview. Im am not using auto layouts. I dont know why the height allways stays the same on my other tableview in my other viewcontroller.. Can someone please help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Auto resize subviews was the property for the main view that was enabled . Disabling this fixed it.